Kafka reactor KafkaReceiver (spring) - how to test?
I can't find a working way to test my kafka consumer that uses a receiver.
The code for the receiver is someting along the way of:
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyAvroTopicConsumer {
  private final ReceiverOptionsService receiverOptionsService;
  private final String myTopic;

  public MyAvroTopicConsumer (ReceiverOptionsService receiverOptionsService,
      @Value("${kafka.receiver.myavrotopicconsumer.topic}") String myTopic) {
    this.receiverOptionsService = receiverOptionsService;
    this.myTopic= myTopic;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void consumeMessages() {
    var receiverOptions = receiverOptionsService.subscribeToTopic(myTopic);

    KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
        .receive()
        .flatMap(record -> {
          var value = record.value();

          if (value instanceof MyAvroEvent myAvroEvent) {
            return doUpdates(myAvroEvent)
                .then(Mono.just(record));
          }

          log.info("Received unsupported record type: " + value.getClass());
          return Mono.just(record);
        })
        .flatMap(record -> record.receiverOffset().commit())
        .subscribe();
  }

  private Flux<Void> doUpdates(MyAvroEvent myAvroEvent) {
      ...
  }

}

I want a way to test if the updates happen, but I can't find a way to in a test send a message to the topic it listens to.
I have tried using the following:
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = "myTestTopic")
public class MyAvroTopicConsumerIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  private ReceiverOptionsService receiverOptionsService;
  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate;
  @Autowired
  private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

  ...

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    ...

    var consumer = new MyAvroTopicConsumer(receiverOptionsService, "myTestTopic");
    consumer.consumeMessages();
  }

  @Test
  public void testReactiveConsumer() throws InterruptedException {
    produceTestMessage("bla");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    ... // asserts here

  }

  private void produceTestMessage(String message) {
    // Create producer properties
    var producerProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafkaBroker);
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

    // Create Kafka producer
    try (Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerProps)) {
      // Send test message to the input topic
      var record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("myTestTopic", message);
      producer.send(record).get(); // Wait for the send operation to complete
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}

What could I be doing something wrong?
Is there a better way?
